# iOS NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

This is my code in ViewController.m file,

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   NSLog(@"%f",[self usedMemory]);
   NSMutableArray *array= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:10000];
       [array addObject:data];
   }
   NSLog(@"%f",[self usedMemory]);

   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
       [array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
   }
   NSLog(@"%f",[self usedMemory]);
}
```

Here is the `usedMemory` method:

```
- (double)usedMemory
{
    task_basic_info_data_t taskInfo;

    mach_msg_type_number_t infoCount = TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;

    kern_return_t kernReturn = task_info(mach_task_self(),

                                     TASK_BASIC_INFO,

                                     (task_info_t)&taskInfo,

                                     &infoCount);
    if (kernReturn != KERN_SUCCESS

       )
    {
        return NSNotFound;
    }
    return taskInfo.resident_size / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
2015-01-26 22:39:00.058 audio_memory_test[9050:874963] 25.011719
2015-01-26 22:39:00.060 audio_memory_test[9050:874963] 26.312500
2015-01-26 22:39:00.060 audio_memory_test[9050:874963] 26.312500
```

Why has memory not been released when I deleted objects in the array? What has the `removeObjectAtIndex` method done? How can I release this memory?

Comment: Who's implementing self:usedMemory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `[self usedMemory]` after the final loop, your objects are still held in memory. The autorelease pool to which they belong hasn't yet been drained; this generally happens when you leave the scope of your source code and the system takes control again.

Comment: How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Fix what? If you want to release the memory specifically, you could put your code within its own `@autoreleasepool` scope. Alternatively, you could use `alloc init` (and `release` if you're not using ARC). If you just want your printouts to reflect your memory shrinking again, simply schedule the `[self usedMemory]` call after you've run out of your scope using `performSelector:afterDelay:` or `dispatch_after` or any other place in your code.

Answer (score 2):

All because [NSMutableData dataWithLength: ] returns an *autoreleased* object, so you get exactly the expected behaviour.

To fix this: Either use [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength: ] or use an autorelease pool.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the problem is that you're creating auto-released objects. Here is a change you could make to your code so your objects would actually be released:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   NSLog(@"%f",[self usedMemory]);

   //all autoreleased objects created inside the braces 
   //of the @autorleasepool directive will be released
   //when we leave the braces
   @autoreleasepool
   {
     NSMutableArray *array= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:10000];
         [array addObject:data];
     }
     NSLog(@"%f",[self usedMemory]);

     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         [array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
     }
   }
   NSLog(@"%f",[self usedMemory]);
}
```

Comment: But there is no need for this. Without the autorelease pool, the objects will be autoreleased after `viewDidAppear:` returns back to the top of the run loop. Adding the autorelease pool simply causes the memory to be cleaned up a split second sooner. It's just not needed.

Comment: It enables the OP to perform the test synchronously. If you wait for the event loop, other memory could be allocated or released, muddying the results.